# "split_part" to structure a column into a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a digital marketing manager and am trying to breakdown my campaigns for sliced analysis. My campaigns are listed in one column as follows.

```
  FR-SRC-PLATFORM | MISC {bw}
  FR-SRC-M2M sim  | Sim {bw}
  ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity {e}
```

I would like to separate each first based on - then | and then on {.

The result being

```
Cola | Colb | Colc    | Col d | Col e
fr   | SRC  | Platform| Misc  | {bw}
```

I have found the following formula that works but there is only one problem...

```
SELECT split_part(your_col,'-',1) cola,
 split_part(your_col,'-',2) colb,
 split_part(split_part(your_col,'-',2),' | ',1) colc,
 split_part(split_part(your_col,' | ',2),' {',1) cold,
 split_part(split_part(your_col,'{',2),'}',1) cole
 /* or 
   split_part(your_col,'{',2) cole
*/
 FROM your_table
```

It will sometimes occur that my campaigns will have a different structure (more keywords) which results in more criteria being separated by the | symbol.  As and example; ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity | SIM | USA {e}.  I would in theory like to keep everything between the first | and first { within the same column.

Is there a way of salvaging this formula or should I search for something from scratch?

Thank you in advanced.

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to redesign the tables so you aren't concatenating values in columns but instead storing individual pieces of data in columns and rows? Because that's the real solution here.

Comment: I am unable to do this as it was never concatenated.  I have seen this done before with SQL so I do know that it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you familiar with `plpgsql`:

```
drop function if exists foo(text, out text, out text, out text, out text, out text);
create function foo(p_input text, out cola text, out colb text, out colc text, out cold text, out cole text)
  returns record immutable language plpgsql as $$
declare
  p1 text; pi1 int;
  p2 text; pi2 int;
  p3 text;
begin
  -- String is like part1 | part2 {part3}
  -- So lets split it to this parts:
  pi1 := position('|' in p_input);
  pi2 := position('{' in p_input);

  p1 := trim(substring(p_input, 1, pi1 - 1));
  p2 := trim(substring(p_input, pi1 + 1, pi2 - pi1 - 1));
  p3 := trim(substring(p_input, pi2));

  -- Debug output
  raise info 'p1: %', p1;
  raise info 'p2: %', p2;
  raise info 'p3: %', p3;

  -- Part1 is like field1-field2-field3:
  cola := split_part(p1, '-', 1);
  colb := split_part(p1, '-', 2);
  colc := split_part(p1, '-', 3);
  -- And the rest:
  cold := p2;
  cole := p3;

  return;
end $$;

with t(x) as (values
  ('FR-SRC-PLATFORM | MISC {bw}'),
  ('FR-SRC-M2M sim  | Sim {bw}'),
  ('ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity {e}'),
  ('ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity | SIM | USA {e}')
)
select *, (foo(x)).* from t;
```

Result:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════╤══════╤══════╤══════════╤══════════════════════════╤══════╗
║                     x                     │ cola │ colb │   colc   │           cold           │ cole ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════════╪══════╪══════╪══════════╪══════════════════════════╪══════╣
║ FR-SRC-PLATFORM | MISC {bw}               │ FR   │ SRC  │ PLATFORM │ MISC                     │ {bw} ║
║ FR-SRC-M2M sim  | Sim {bw}                │ FR   │ SRC  │ M2M sim  │ Sim                      │ {bw} ║
║ ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity {e}             │ ES   │ SRC  │ IOT      │ Connectivity             │ {e}  ║
║ ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity | SIM | USA {e} │ ES   │ SRC  │ IOT      │ Connectivity | SIM | USA │ {e}  ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════╧══════╧══════╧══════════╧══════════════════════════╧══════╝
```

And it will be very simple to adapt the function's logic if you will found yet another case of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with regex substring

```
with e AS ( VALUES  ('FR-SRC-PLATFORM | MISC {bw}')
      ,('FR-SRC-M2M sim  | Sim {bw}')
      ,('ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity {e}')
      ,('AXE|SPADE|SHOVEL{test}')
)
SELECT column1,substring(column1 from $$^([^|]*)\|$$ ) as a
    ,substring(column1 from $$^[^|]*\|([^{]*)$$ ) as b
    ,substring(column1 from $x$[{](.*)[}]$$x$ ) as c
FROM e;
```

gives

```
            column1            |        a         |       b        |  c   
 ------------------------------+------------------+----------------+------
 FR-SRC-PLATFORM | MISC {bw}   | FR-SRC-PLATFORM  |  MISC          | bw
 FR-SRC-M2M sim  | Sim {bw}    | FR-SRC-M2M sim   |  Sim           | bw
 ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity {e} | ES-SRC-IOT       |  Connectivity  | e
 AXE|SPADE|SHOVEL{test}        | AXE              | SPADE|SHOVEL   | test
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Could you please adapt the formula to the structure that is desired up top and or provide some explanation as to how this formula works.  I am new to PostgreSQL and just need to create one simple workflow that would automate my reporting.  Thanks again.