# “split_part” to structure a column into a table?

Tags: postgresql

I am a digital marketing manager and am trying to breakdown my campaigns for sliced analysis. My campaigns are listed in one column as follows.

```
  FR-SRC-PLATFORM | MISC {bw}
  FR-SRC-M2M sim  | Sim {bw}
  ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity {e}
```

I would like to separate each first based on - then | and then on {.

```
The result being 
Cola | Colb | Colc    | Col d | Col e
fr   | SRC  | Platform| Misc  | {bw}
```

I have found the following formula that works but there is only one problem...

```
SELECT split_part(your_col,'-',1) cola,
 split_part(your_col,'-',2) colb,
 split_part(split_part(your_col,'-',2),' | ',1) colc,
 split_part(split_part(your_col,' | ',2),' {',1) cold,
 split_part(split_part(your_col,'{',2),'}',1) cole
 /* or 
   split_part(your_col,'{',2) cole
*/
 FROM your_table
```

It will sometimes occur that my campaigns will have a different structure (more keywords) which results in more criteria being separated by the | symbol.  As and example; ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity | SIM | USA {e}.  **I would need to keep everything between | and { within the same column.**
Is there a way of salvaging this formula or should I search for something from scratch?

Here is an additional example
ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity | SIM | USA {e}.

```
ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD                   |ColE
ES  |SRC |IOT |Connectivity| SIM | USA|{e}
```

Thank you

Comment: I think I've seen this question before recently, perhaps from you or someone else.  In general, you might need a parser to handle this problem.  But in any case, you could handle this outside of Postgres, generate a proper CSV file, and then import that into the database.

Comment: so what's the wanted result for you sample?..

Comment: They are listed up top, however, as stated at the end of the question I would need everything always between the first | and { to be contained within column D.

Comment: please `ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity | SIM | USA {e}.` devide into a,b,c,d,e in the post

Comment: Col A = ES                   Colb = SRC                  Colc = IOT                    Cold=  Connectivity | SIM | USA -*THE NUMBER OF BRACKETS HERE CAN VARY                     Cole={e}

Comment: I stuck this in at the end as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790931/split-part-to-structure-a-column-into-a-table

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if here can be any graceful solution. What I do - cut by curly bracket to two to exclude last column, and then just reuse your code. For last delimiter I use `cc` column concatted with '|' - it of course requires accurate syntax. anyway:

```
t=# with a(v) as (values('ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity | SIM | USA {e}'),('FR-SRC-PLATFORM | MISC {bw}'))
, pre as (select split_part(v,'{',1) a,split_part(v,'{',2) b from a)
select split_part(a,'-',1) ca, split_part(a,'-',2) cb, split_part(split_part(a,'-',3),'|',1) cc, split_part(split_part(a,'-',3),split_part(split_part(a,'-',3),'|',1)||'|',2) cd, '{'||b ce from pre;
 ca | cb  |    cc     |             cd             |  ce
----+-----+-----------+----------------------------+------
 ES | SRC | IOT       |  Connectivity | SIM | USA  | {e}
 FR | SRC | PLATFORM  |  MISC                      | {bw}
(2 rows)
```

so in your case the query would be:

```
with a(v) as (select your_col from your_table)
    , pre as (select split_part(v,'{',1) a,split_part(v,'{',2) b from a)
    select split_part(a,'-',1) ca, split_part(a,'-',2) cb, split_part(split_part(a,'-',3),'|',1) cc, split_part(split_part(a,'-',3),split_part(split_part(a,'-',3),'|',1)||'|',2) cd, '{'||b ce from pre;
```

Comment: Thaks Vao,  is there a way to create this query without actually having to refer to the text?  I would like to reference the entire column instead.

Comment: @IanJames not sure I understand. updated the question trying to guess

Comment: Would it be possible to add a concatenation of two columns from the source campaign within this query?  I would be needing this for reference as a primary collumn.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Courtesy of Vao **

t=# with a(v) as (values('ES-SRC-IOT | Connectivity | SIM | USA {e}'),
('FR-SRC-PLATFORM | MISC {bw}'))
, pre as (select split_part(v,'{',1) a,split_part(v,'{',2) b from a)
select split_part(a,'-',1) ca, split_part(a,'-',2) cb, split_part
(split_part (a,'-',3),'|',1) cc, split_part(split_part(a,'-',3),
split_part   (split_part(a,'-',3),'|',1)||'|',2) cd, '{'||b ce from pre;
 ca | cb  |    cc     |             cd             |  ce
----+-----+-----------+----------------------------+------
 ES | SRC | IOT       |  Connectivity | SIM | USA  | {e}
 FR | SRC | PLATFORM  |  MISC                      | {bw}
```

(2 rows)